# Binding textblock so that one change of variable on one page reflects in UI

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml, xbap

Basic layout ***(VB.NET & WPF/XBAP)***:

I have a MainPage - mainpage.xaml
Inside the MainPage I have a frame that hosts other pages. The first page that is auto loaded is the LogIn - LogIn.xaml

The user enters their email to login (no password required, just email to identify, its an internal app so passwords are not required or even wanted by users).

On MainPage.xaml the header should have a "Hello " TexBlock (name: ui_txbUserName). The LogIn page has a method which on submit gets the UserID (for other reasons and saves it) and the User Name.

I want to change the ui_txbUserName when the person logs in and update if he/she logs out of one account into another. I have looked at INotifyPropertyChanged and Dependency Properties and im just not sure how to go about doing this! Any help would be awesome!!!

Thanks!

UsingOfficerID - its a global variable set when a person logs in, its used all over the place in the application.

I have tried the Following inside the sample app:

http://www.2shared.com/file/68enzucg/SampleApp.html

None of this is reflected in the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I thought I'd add another answer which addresses the specifics of your sample application.  I've had a look through the sample, but the code seems to be a bit in a state of flux!  Firstly, you haven't set the DataContext of MainWindow (the view) anywhere, this should be set to an instance of your view model (UserViewModel.vb, although I would consider renaming either the view or the view model so that they are e.g. MainView and MainViewModel).

You can set the DataContext in several ways, using a view first or view model first approach.  One quick way to start testing is in the constructor of your view:

```
// MainWindow.xaml.vb
Class MainWindow

  Public Sub New()

      InitializeComponent()

      Me.DataContext = New UserViewModel()

  End Sub

End Class
```

Now, in your UserViewModel, you have a UserName property, but it seems to return and set a User object username property.  Even though the user object never seems to be set anywhere.  To keep things simple, I just used a string instead with a new backing field:

```
Private _username As String
Public Property UserName() As String
     Get
         Return _username
     End Get
     Set(ByVal Value As String)
         _username = Value
         MyBase.OnPropertyChanged("UserName")
     End Set
End Property
```

Originally, you had called MyBase.OnPropertyChanged("Address") for some reason??  Maybe this was a copy/paste error, but the string value must match the name of the property whose value has changed, as the binding engine will use reflection to retrieve the new property value.

Finally, I just changed the binding expression in MainWindow.xaml

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding UserName}" />
```

Because the DataContext isn't explicitly set on the TextBlock, it will use the DataContext of the view (UserControl) which is set to an instance of UserViewModel.  This means that it will bind to a UserName property on that DataContext which is what you want.  To test it, you can set the value of Me.UserName = "Something" in the constructor of the UserViewModel.

Hopefully you can see how the binding works for strings, and you can work out where you need to go to get it working for your User type.

Comment: Ah you are awesome! I get it!!!! FINALLY! I find it really hard to grasp the content unless I see it work - takes me like 40 breakpoints but i get it :)

Just bought the WPF Unleased and VB.NET 2010 books - time to learn some more, can't ride the vb.net 2005 codebase forever.

Comment: I have updated the the Code to reflect the changes - how do I go about updating the ViewModel so that it reflects in the UI?

I have the updated code here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4086656/SampleApp.zip

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm assuming that you're not using the MVVM design pattern to build your application?  If not, I suggest you have a look into doing so, as it provides many benefits, most notably separation of concerns and testability.

In MVVM, your views (.xaml files) would have their DataContext set as your view model.  So, for you main page, I would have a MainViewModel.cs and MainView.xaml.  http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html is a nice article on the MVVM design pattern.

Your view model should then implement INotifyPropertyChanged (you shouldn't use dependency properties on view models).  This interface has one event on it called PropertyChanged which you can invoke to notify any clients (in this case the WPF binding client) that a change to your property has occurred.  This invalidates the binding, and causes that properties getter to be called again to retrieve the new value.

Normally, as with any .NET event, you would create a helper method to invoke the event, and pass it the name of the property which has changed as a string.  See the article for examples.

In your case, the MainViewModel would need a reference to the current user, e.g. as a public property of type IUser, which in the setter calls your helper method to invoke the PropertyChanged event.

```
private IUser currentUser;

public IUser CurrentUser
{
  get
  {
    return this.currentUser;
  }

  set
  {
    this.currentUser = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentUser");
  }
}

// constructor
public MainViewModel(IUser currentUser)
{
  this.CurrentUser = currentUser;
}

protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
  if (handler != null)
  {
    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Assuming IUser has forename and surname properties, you would bind to it in your view using:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="Hello {0} {1}">
      <Binding Path="CurrentUser.FirstName" />
      <Binding Path="CurrentUser.LastName" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Now whenever the CurrentUser changes, your UI will update.  Note that if you want the UI to update if a property of the user type changes (e.g. forename), then your concrete implementation of IUser will also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I've read the above articles a few more but they are all in C# which is hard to understand for me. I have included my previous code if that helps any.

Comment: Looking at your code, you create a new instance of your view model, set the datacontext of the view to be that view model, and then you create a new user and set its username.  However, you're not doing anything with that new user?  So the view model knows nothing about it.  You're binding to Users.UserName, but the Users property is a collection of User, so has no UserName property.  I think you either want to change the binding to use the viewmodels UserName property, and set it in the loading code, or set the User property, and bind to User.UserName.

Comment: Hi,
I've been trying to get that to work but still nothing - could you by chance have a look at this?
currentUser = UserDS.Tables("User").Select("UID = " & UsingOfficerID)(0).Item("FName").ToString

Here it says current user cannot be string. Even after fixing that it doesn't show up in the UI at all.

Sorry about his but I've never really used this before.

Comment: Sorry, could you update your question to include your latest code.  Have you tried just building a simple app with one view model which implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and one string property which invokes the PropertyChanged event, and then bind a TextBlock Text value to that property?

Comment: Let me try that (simple app) - and I will get back to you asap :)

Comment: Hi Devdigital - thanks for putting up with me man. I have attached a sample app - I've learned VB.Net on my own and normally work in WinForms so this is new to me and im having serious difficulty understanding it.